# Python chatbot implementation to website?

Tags: python, frontend, backend, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I have made a chatbot in python code. And also have a GUI to go alongside it. Does anyone know the best way to implement this code into a website. Or is it best to use a service such as Dialogflow?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the  [flask framework](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/) to make your chatbot working on the website, the nice thing is you can use Dialogflow still if you wanted to.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Do you know if you can use Flask to make a small chatbot window in the corner of a website?